# .NET MAUI FilePicker not working when requestedExecutionLevel set to requireAdministrator

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows

I am trying to build a .NET MAUI App for Windows platform which requires admin permissions for working. For launching the app in admin, I added the following lines to the `app.manifest`

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```

This launches the app in admin mode fine, but in the app, I have a button that launches the `FilePicker.PickAsync`. This works in non admin mode, but when I start the debug mode in admin, the app just closes, no crash, the mode in Visual Studio remains Debug, no breakpoint hit.
What could the issue be?

Alternatively, I want to launch a process in admin mode and also get the output from it (so cannot use `processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` and `processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";`). I want to make it generalized, so no hardcoded admin name and password. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the limit (or bug) in the native windows app. You can check the existed issue about [Trying to use a FileOpenPicker while running the app as Administrator will crash the app](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2504) on the github.

And you can follow up this issue or try [the workaround which used the win32 api](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2504#issuecomment-1483915593).